# How might I go about modeling the product of two random Poisson distributed variables that are not necessarily independent?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I think the title might capture the entire question but for clarity's sake let me expand here.  I have several Poisson distributed random variables, and want to model the product of pairs of these variables.  I have reason to believe that many of these variables will be correlated with each other, so it seems like a Poisson model would not be a reasonable approximation of all of the resulting distributions.  Is there a distribution that might be appropriate that doesn't assume independence of the variables I'm taking the product of?

Comment: Do you know if the correlations are positive or negative?

Answer (score 2):

This paper seems to discuss multivariate poisson distribution with covariance structures.  Check it out. Happy reading!

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11222-005-4069-4